# javascript (200-200)/100 = 9009

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, divide

So I am working on a formula with javascript. 
and this is the formula. The data for the tank variables is gathered from inputfields.

```
y = ((tank1 + tank2 + (tank 3 /25)) - (tank4 + tank4))/100;
alert(y);
```

so for `tank1 = 100` `tank2 = 100` and `tank3 = 0` `tank4 = 100` and `tank5 =100`

according to javascript the answer to this is **9009** while it is supposed to be `0`.

for `tank1 = 90` `tank2 = 90` `tank3 = 0` `tank4 = 90` and `tank5 = 90` `answer = 818.6`

I tried changing the divisions to multiplications `/25` to `0.04` and `/100` to `0.01` but the results were the same. 
I also tried renaming the tanks in case they were referring to the wrong tanks.
I have also tried alerting the tanks and they gave the right inserted numbers back.
I am running Jquery.

Does anyone Know what is causing this?

Comment: Returns 0 for me http://jsfiddle.net/J8ZBk/ and http://jsfiddle.net/J8ZBk/1/

Comment: `tank1 = 100` or `tank1 = "100"`? Look like you need to parse string

Comment: @roasted Checks out; post that as the answer.

Comment: OP: As you're using strings, tank1 + tank2 is "100100", not 200.

Comment: @roasted You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @KevinB I mean that, e.g: `y = ((+tank1 + +tank2 + (tank3 /25)) - (+tank4 + +tank4))/100;` Or use parseInt()  http://jsfiddle.net/m4WVe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `parseInt(tankX)` for every tank variable and it will work as expected.

This is because your values come from input fields as strings not integers.

Reference: **[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

Comment: @user2725775: Since this solution worked, it would be helpful if you would accept the answer.  (Then others won't have to read the whole thing to see that it's been answered.)